# Вычисляемое поле в sql, показала с примером вычисляемое поле, текущая стоимость

Tags: mysql, sql

Написала IF потому что не знаю как это в sql. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше это все реализовать через представление, ХП или как.

```
текущая дата - день.месяц.год  
дата ввода в эксплуатацию- день.месяц.год  
срок_амортизации=5

02.09.2012 -  
12.10.2000 =   -10.-1.12  
переменная а =-10  
переменная b= -1  
переменная с = 12  
int mesiac;  
int god;  
if (b<0)  
{   
  mesiac=12+b  
  c=c-1;

}

if (c>срок амортизации)  
   {god=срок амортизации}  
esle (c<срок амортизации){ 
   c=|c-срок амортизации|  
}
```

текущая стоимость= Первоначальная стоимость - ((Годовая_сумма_амортизации * god +   Годовая_сумма_амортизации /12 * mesiac)))
+(сумму поля стоимость обслуживания где совпадает 
   таблица_стоимость.кодОС=таблица_Обслуживание.кодОС)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Как писать UDF MySQL](http://www.sqlexamples.info/PHP/mysql_udf1.htm)